# Is there a way to remap the android numeric keyboard to give the decimal and negative sign their own independent keys?

Tags: android

I have an app that has the following EditText field:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:text="@{viewModel.whereINeedANegativeNumber}"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

What this produces is the following keyboard when a user clicks into the field:

[image]

The testers believe it isn't intuitive, and they are correct, to have to double-tap the [ .- ] key in order to enter a negative sign.

What I would like is a keyboard like the following (notice the new location of the decimal and negative sign):

[image]

So ... is there a way to remap the keyboard to give the decimal and negative sign their own, independent keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ~25,000 Android device models. What the input method editor (soft keyboard) will look like will depend on the device model, and in some cases the third-party keyboard that the user installed. Things like `inputType` provide a hint to the keyboard, but the rendering of the keyboard is up to the developers of the keyboard.

> is there a way to remap the keyboard to give the decimal and negative sign their own, independent keys?

No. You seem to have a reasonable `inputType` value. IMHO, I agree that a `numberDecimal|numberSigned` `EditText` should have dedicated keys for the decimal separator and the negative sign. However, that is not up to us, and the behavior will vary by device.

Comment: Well, rats! Thanks for the input. I believe what I will do is create a numeric keypad in the layout and disable the EditText input with `inputType:none` and then hook up my custom keypad to the input fields.

Comment: @Brian: If you go this route, please keep accessibility in mind.

Comment: What do you mean by "accessibility"? Are you referring to people with disabilities? Also, this is an internal app only, only a specific subset of people will ever use it.

Comment: @Brian: "Are you referring to people with disabilities?" -- yes.

Comment: Gotcha ... Like I said, though, this is an internal app and will never be used by people with disabilities. Thanks for the input!